# jQuery suppress parent element event handler

Tags: jquery

I have a table where click on row shows and hides details of item and also I have a link with custom `onclick` handler in a cell inside the row. How to prevent row's `onclick` handler execution in the link `onclick` handler. So I'd like to open new window by link clicking without showing/hiding details.

Comment: Where is the code? and read https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Answer (score 1):

Refer about [stopPropagation()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_stoppropagation.asp) which used to prevent **bubbling event** when child clicked where parent too have `onclick` event. Check below snippet for simple example as you haven't shared any code.

```js
$('.mySpan').on('click', function(e) {
  console.log('span clicked');
  e.stopPropagation();
});
$('.myDiv').on('click', function(e) {
  console.log('div clicked');
});
```

```css
.myDiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.mySpan {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myDiv">
  <span class="mySpan">My span text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see any posibility how to mark your answer as solution

Comment: ha ha there will be a tick mark below reputation up/down votes!